# Tomcat share lib folder

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a war file which not include the lib jars. I create share folder under the lib folder, put all jar files in it, and update the catalina.properties file. It's working on my Mac, but not the centos7 server. I check the centos7 tomcat log, it shows the log4j cannot be found, but the jar is in the share folder. What's other possible place to check?

thanks

catalina.properties

```
   shared.loader="${catalina.base}/lib/share","${catalina.base}/lib/share/*.jar","${catalina.home}/lib/share","${catalina.home}/lib/share/*.jar"
```

tomcat 8.5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This my own mistake, add  to the ../conf/context.xml file, the antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" should be remove!

correct sample:

```
 <Context>

<!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
<!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->
</Context>
```